# How to get two-way binding working using input within a directive?

Tags: angularjs

My initial goal was to create components that have input definitions in them, and collect everything back on the parent controller.  There are hacky methods that I've had to use to accomplish this ($rootScope, $on), but I would like to know where I went wrong in my code.  This is about two-way binding between directives and controllers ("=")

my view:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    my input value: {{variable}}
    <div my-directive input="variable"></div>
</div>
```

my controller/directive

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
    $scope.variable = "initial value";
})
.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        scope: { eggplant: "=input" },
        template: "Change the parent value: <input ng-model='eggplant'/>" +
                  "<br> eggplant: {{eggplant}}"
    }
});
```

For whatever reason, this doesn't work.  I've tried some other configurations on the template, such as...

```
...
template: "Change the parent value: <input ng-model='{{eggplant}}'/>"
...

...
template: "Change the parent value: <input ng-model='{eggplant}'/>"
...
```

But ultimately, I've had to add a controller (with $scope) to the directive, add a ng-change function, and when the directive changes, attach that to the directive controller $scope... But this doesn't feel like the right way to approach this problem.  Can anyone reveal where I went wrong?

```
...
.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        scope: { eggplant: "=input" },
        template: "Change the parent value: "+
                  "<input ng-model='eggplant' ng-change='change(eggplant)'/>",
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.change(val){
                // I also have a $rootscope hack I can sell you :P
                $scope.eggplant = val;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your directive looks off. In your scope, you want to assign `eggplant` to `input` in this case, not `variable`:

```
.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        scope: { eggplant: "=input" },
        template: "Change the parent value: <input ng-model='eggplant'/>" +
                  "<br> eggplant: {{eggplant}}"
    }
})
```

You're telling the directive to bind on the attribute, not the value name.

Comment: Hey Manny, thanks for your response.  Yea, that was my mistake.  In the actual code, that mistake isn't present.

Comment: Ah ok. Could you clarify more on what you mean by it not working? I don't see anything wrong with what you have and my own test is showing the same: http://plnkr.co/edit/izVo7ojbNUpl9BN8ySIf?p=preview

Comment: Well that's a little vindicating, but also very perplexing!  I KNEW I had it right!

By "not working", I mean that I can set 'eggplant' in the directive to "initial value" through 'myCtrl', but when I change that value within the directive through the input, the changes are not reflected on myCtrl.

It's certainly a head scratcher now.  I'll have to see what dependencies might be messing with the angular juice.